# Problemas de velocidad cargando subcapas con Leaflet usando Svelte

Tags: leaflet, svelte

tengo un objeto que se compone de categorias con sus elementos(latitud,longitud y nombre) pretendo generar subcapas, lo logro pero el problema es que tarda tanto que hace inviable el programa, paso el codigo por si alguien pudiese ayudarme:
recorro las categorias y las asigno como L.markerGroup
recorro los elementos para asignarlos a los markerGroup  y los agrupo markercluster
y luego asigno los markergroup al controlador de capas para que sedespliegue en el lateral del mapa y segun la categoria muestre uno u otros elementos que aparecen agrupados dado la gran densidad de marcadores

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import L from "leaflet";
  import "../../../node_modules/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css"
  import { MarkerClusterGroup } from 'leaflet.markercluster';
  import { store } from "../../lib/store.js"
  
  let map;

  const layerGroups = {};

  function createMarkerGroup(category) {
    const markerGroup = new MarkerClusterGroup();
    for (let element of $store[category]) {
      const marker = L.marker([element.latitude, element.longitude]).bindPopup(element.name);
      markerGroup.addLayer(marker);
    }
    return markerGroup;
  }
  
  function createLayerGroups() {
    for (let category in $store) {
      const markerGroup = createMarkerGroup(category);  // llamo funcion con parametro categoria y recoge clcuster
      layerGroups[category] = L.layerGroup(); // genero las categorias
      layerGroups[category].addLayer(markerGroup); // añado los grupos a la capa
    }
  }

  onMount(() => {
    // Creamos un mapa de Leaflet
    map = L.map('mymap').setView([42.88805200, -8.0456900], 8);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }).addTo(map);

    createLayerGroups(); // llamo a  la funcion q llama a la funcion

    // Agregamos todas las capas a un controlador de capas
    const controlLayers = L.control.layers({}, layerGroups, {
      position: 'bottomright',
      collapsed: false,
    }).addTo(map);
  });
</script>

<div id="mymap" style="height: 600px;width:900px" />

Muchas graciass
```